# javascript securty: an AJAX call to record the user's screen resolution, is it possible to prevent fake numbers?

Tags: javascript, security, csrf, javascript-security

This is a javascript security question:  suppose a page finds out the screen resolution of the computer, such as 1024 x 768, and want to use an AJAX call to log this data into the DB.

Is there a way to actually prevent fake data from being entered into the DB?  I think whatever the HTML or Javascript does, the user can reverse engineer the code so that some fake numbers get entered into the DB, or is there a way prevent it from happening totally? (100% secure).

**Update**: or in a similar situation... if i write a simple javascript game... is there a way for the user to send back the score by AJAX and lie about their score?

Comment: Why would a user want to lie about their resolution? What if they use different machines in different sessions (desktop at work with two monitors, and laptop elsewhere), and those machines have different resolutions?

Comment: please see update above in a similar situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start with the assumption that the user you are communicating with is malicious, then no; there is nothing you can do to control what data they pass you.  Certainly not with 100% certainty - in the worst case, they can use network tools to rewrite or replace any "correct" content with whatever they want.

If you just want to prevent casual maliciousness, you could obfuscate or encrypt your code and/or data.  This will not deter a determined attacker.

If you actually trust the real user, but suspect that others might try to impersonate them, you can use other techniques like a dynamic canary: send the user a random number, and if they return that same number to you, you know that it really came from them.  (Or you're being hit by a man-in-the-middle attack, but hey; that's what SSL is for.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to stop users from sending any numbers they like back from JavaScript.

I think the best you could do is do some sort of check on the server-side to make sure the numbers sent back look like a realistic resolution.

I'm not sure why someone would spend the time to spoof those numbers in the first place though.

Comment: A sanity check is obviously a good idea.  But you're right it doesn't guarantee accurate data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  Since you're using client-side code, you have to tell the 
user's computer (and thus the user) in one way or another, whatever encryption or obfuscation you're using.  There's no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

For the resolution, it would basically be impossible to determine if it's valid resolution. My resolution is usually sent to the server as 5120 x 1600, which seems pretty unrealistic, but it's because the 2 screens are often sent as 1. Otherwise, there is a such a huge variety of possibilities in screen resolutions and screen configurations, you'd probably remove a lot of valid ones, although they might be few.

For the game score, you could do additional checks that make it more complicated to check. Things like sending multiple notices of the score throughout the game and requiring X number to ensure that the score received is valid. (IE, must receive one between 200-300, 400-500, 700-800 and then the final score of 1000.) With the final score, you could also have some kind of encrypted value that can only be used once or that contains some data with a CRC on it. Basically, in the end, require receiving other data than just the score, especially for higher scores.

Comment: Depending on the game, like if it's a browser based game, the best way to do it would just be to calculate the score on the server itself and not bother with AJAX, but for flash games and the like this certainly isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To attempt an answer by elaborating on comments made by Dok, and yourself, there is a clear distinction between manipulating an application to 'cheat' it out of something, whether it be an online business to get something cheaper or a MMPORG to get more experience, than manipulating it in such a way that it renders the interface incorrectly and diminishes the overall user experience for that particular (hacker?) user.

Your time would be better spent focusing on other aspects of your site. I don't recommend the users of my site manipulate the HTML to make it look funny on their machines, but I'm not going to go all out and obfuscate my server output to stop them from hurting themselves. In your case, range checking against pre-defined safe values, making use of the DB, to ensure the user is viewing with an 'allowed' resolution puts unnecessary burden on your application, and takes time to do.